# Pip does not install tensorflow in the conda env

Tags: windows, tensorflow, pip

I got something weird on Windows (I don't use it since 2012). I created a conda env long time ago with tensorflow 2.2.0. Now, I want to update tensorflow to the latest. As in Linux, I activate the env and I run `pip install tensorflow`. The problem that pip installs it in the global package, not in the env.

Here are some logs:

here when I try to uninstall tensorflow 2.2.0. It does not detect it and it detects 2.3.1 which is installed in global package
[image]

I think the problem is coming from pip path:
[image]

I checked and I see that pip install everything here `c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages`

I tried to create a new environment but I got the same results!!

Anyone got already this problem?

Comment: Could you pls show the command that you are using.

Comment: @CForce99 I edit my question

Comment: where is your venv stored (what's the path)?

Comment: what command did you use to install it to your vnev?

Comment: Why do you expect 2.2.0 to be installed? `pip install tensorflow` will install the latest available version of TF, currently being 2.3.1. Run `pip show tensorflow` to print metadata of the installed package, it will most probably be 2.3.0.

Comment: @hoefling, I want to update the 2.2.0 version to the latest one. running `pip install tensorflow` in myenv install `tensorflow 2.3.1` in the global package not in the myenv!!!!